# Existence of homomorphism from $GO(2n,\mathbb{C})$ to $\mathbb{C}^*$ that doesn't lose too much information

Tags: matrices, group-theory, characters

L.S.,

Denote $GO(2n,\mathbb{C})$ the group of matrices that leave an inner product invariant up to a scalar. We have for all $A \in GO(2n,\mathbb{C}), v,w$ vectors, that: $\langle A(v),A(w)\rangle = \lambda_A \langle v,w \rangle$.

It is known that the function $f$ that maps $A$ to $\lambda_A$ is a homomorphism from $GO(2n,\mathbb{C})$ to $\mathbb{C}^*$. However I find it somewhat unfortunate that we lose too much information, since for instance $f(-I) = f(I)$. Is there maybe a way to construct a homomorphism from $GO(2n,\mathbb{C})$ to $\mathbb{C}^*$ that doesn't lose this particular information? So that we have $f(-A) \neq f(A)$ for all $A \in GO(2n,\mathbb{C})$? I already found out that we can factor $A$ as $A = ab$, with $b \in O(2n,\mathbb{C})$ and $a^2 = \lambda_AI$.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n>1$, I don't think it is possible.

Denote $f:GO(2n,\mathbb{C})\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ a group morphism. You might already know that $SO(2n,\mathbb{C})$ is a simple Lie group. In particular, $SO(2n,\mathbb{C})$ contains no non-trivial normal connected subgroups.

It means that $Ker(f)\cap SO(2n,\mathbb{C})$ is either $SO(2n,\mathbb{C})$ or discrete. If your group morphism $f$ were not $SO(2n,\mathbb{C})$ then $SO(2n,\mathbb{C})$ quotiented by a discrete subgroup would be isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^*$ which is not possible if $n>1$ (for dimensional reason).

Hence a group morphism  $f:GO(2n,\mathbb{C})\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ not only needs to trivialize $-I$ but also any element of $SO(2n,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Clément, such an argument was exactly what I was looking earlier for but couldn't find. I really appreciate you answer, thank you. Could you maybe specify just a little bit what you mean with ''If your group .. dimensional reason).''?

Comment: @WillemBeek, you are welcome. What I mean about this... We are working with complex Lie groups, so the group morphism $f$ is smooth. Since the kernel is discrete,  differential at the identity has for kernel the tangent space of the kernel of $f$ which is trivial since the kernel is discrete. Hence $T_{1_G}f$ the differential of $f$ at the identity is injective but it implies that the Lie algebra of $SO(2n,\mathbb{C})$ is included in the Lie algebra of $\mathbb{C}^*$ which is $1$-dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$ ...

Comment: ...It implies that $SO(2n,\mathbb{C})$ is at most $1$-dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$ but its dimension is $\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$, so $n=1$.

Comment: Once again, thank you very much.